# How to remove a string from left side of a bigger string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a variable which can send me data like:-

`thumb_8_2393_Shades 1.jpg`, `hanger-cloth.jpg` & `Red-Lehenga-1.jpg`;

Now, when the value will have 'thumb_' at the left side, I want to discard the 'thumb_' string from the full value.

So I wrote this code:-

```
$pImgBig = trim($pI['image'],'thumb');
```

What the issue I am facing is, it is also removing the `'h'` from the `'hanger-cloth.jpg'`.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: `$filename=str_replace('thumb_','',$filename);` ?

Comment: your variable have comma separated value?

Comment: @RamRaider and what if the string contains 'thumb_' in the middle, but not on the left?

Comment: @Anant Precisely, no. It doesn't contain comma separated values.

Comment: $filename=preg_replace('/^thumb_/','',$filename);

Comment: is that likely? using str_replace would remove it so probably not what you want, better to use a regex in that case

Comment: @RamRaider, I am not handy with regex. Could you please help me in that matter?

Comment: The snippet given by @splash58 looks the business

Comment: using `str_replace` you could do `$filename=substr($filename,0,6)==='thumb_' ? str_replace( 'thumb_', '', $filename ) : $filename;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can use `preg_replace()` like below:-***

```
$pImgBig = preg_replace('/^thumb_/','',$pI['image']);

<?php
$data = 'hanger-cloth.jpg';

$data = preg_replace('/^thumb_/','',$data);
echo $data;

$data1 = 'thumb_8_2393_Shades 1.jpg';

$data1 = preg_replace('/^thumb_/','',$data1);
echo $data1;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/606785

***@RaimRaider  give a very nice sugestion of using `str_replace()` in correct way like below:-***

```
<?php
$data = 'hanger-cloth.jpg';

$data =  substr($data,0,6)==='thumb_' ? str_replace( 'thumb_', '', $data ) : $data;
echo $data;

$data1 = 'thumb_8_2393_Shades 1.jpg';

$data1 =  substr($data1,0,6)==='thumb_' ? str_replace( 'thumb_', '', $data1 ) : $data1;
echo $data1;

$filename=substr($filename,0,6)==='thumb_' ? str_replace( 'thumb_', '', $filename ) : $filename;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/606800

Comment: `You have to use` not true, and using a regex for something like this often leads to problems, as regexes are so often misunderstood.

Comment: In this case we have to use regex, as we only require to remove sub-string at the beginning of the string.  `preg_replace('/^thumb_/','',$data)`

Comment: @anant, you can't use str_replace. Run your code for the value `8_2393_thumb_Shades 1.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `strpos` and `substr` functions:

```
$images = ['thumb_8_2393_Shades 1.jpg','hanger-cloth.jpg', 'Red-Lehenga-1.jpg'];
foreach ($images as &$img) {
    if (strpos($img, 'thumb_') === 0) {  // if file name starts with 'thumb_'
        $img = substr($img, 6);
    }
}

print_r($images);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8_2393_Shades 1.jpg
    [1] => hanger-cloth.jpg
    [2] => Red-Lehenga-1.jpg
)
```